# Recursive dividing by 3

Tags: java, recursion, division

Using recursion, I'm trying to divide an input by 3 all the way to the result being below 1.

So far here is what I have, but my output always turns out to be like `1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1`. I believe I know where my error is on the code, but I can't think what input to use or if I coded my methods wrong. I placed a note where I believe the problem is and was wondering if anyone could support in giving a hint on how to fix this.

As well, how can I end the loop?

```
package divideby3;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DivideBy3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter number >= 1:");
        int n = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        System.out.println("\n Negative result is:" + n);

        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            System.out.print(Recusion(i) + " ");
        }
    }

    public static double Recusion(double n) {
        if(n >= 1) {
            //not sure what to put here
            return ;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Sorry thats not number over 1!");
        }

        return Recusion(n / 3);
    }

    public static double Loop(double n) {
        if(n >= 1) {
            return 1;
        }

        double input = 0, divide = 3;
        for(double i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            divide = (input / divide);
        }

        return divide; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You `Loop` method's first condition is also wrong, given you want it to divide if it's greater than/equal to 1.  The loop itself has several far more serious problems, though...

Comment: Could you give an example input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you don't understand the concept of recursion. It would be beneficial to read up on it. Simply put, Recursion is a technique where a function calls itself recursively until a condition is met.

Here is a simple example of how it works.

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.print(RecursiveDivision(100,3));
  }

  public static double RecursiveDivision(double dividend, int divisor) {
    if (dividend < 1)
      return dividend;

    return RecursiveDivision(dividend/divisor, divisor);
  }
```

Comment: It is helpful to provide the reason why an answer is downvoted.

Comment: Gabe - pretty sure 90% of this site is homework questions - if anything I DID my work and im asking for help/hints, not the answer...moving along.

Tech - clearly, and i can try to read as much into it, but sometimes I do better if shown with examples of my direction, not random book entries. That being said - this example has helped so thank you.

Comment: @Mr.Caramel Great, mark it as the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Standing by to make sure I can figure it out before marking it. The user input is printing out how many "divided answers" will show, rather than dividing that input - so I'm working to solve that. Once I have it down without further questions I'll mark.

Comment: @Mr.Caramel Could you give an example or update your question as to what you mean? I don't quite understand.

Comment: Which disregard - I figured out why it did that, now to plug in the proper math in the right places.

Edit: here is what i meant 
Enter number >=: (user inputs 4)
1
1
1
1

Comment: I took a step back and re-read my assignment, and i misunderstood that I do not need user input, but rather just a random number. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Mr.Caramel why don't you mark this as best answer then? That would have been even easier than throwing out your last comment.

Answer (score -2):

As previously mentioned

```
     public static void main(String[] args)
      {
    //you decide the number at n

System.out.print(RecursiveDivision(n,3));
}

public static double RecursiveDivision(double dividend, int divisor) {
      if (dividend < 1)
      return dividend;

return RecursiveDivision(dividend/divisor, divisor);
}
```